# Burninate tag [malayalam]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should the tag [malayalam](/questions/tagged/malayalam) exist?

The tag summary is:

> Malayalam is a language spoken primarily in the state of Kerala, India.

Which seems rather out of scope as a tag on SO to me.

A particular user is suggesting a lot of edits which add this tag, and a lot of them are being approved.

What is the consensus about this tag? Have I missed something about this particular language that makes it warrant a tag?

Comment: It's not large enough to be considered for cjk, and it's too narrow to be considered for just Unicode or utf-8.  I'm thinking it stays.

Comment: Related discussion available here: [Tags for natural languages help in content categorization and searching of posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179681/tags-for-natural-languages-help-in-content-categorization-and-searching-of-posts).

Comment: The questions under the tag are genuine programming problems (except [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546438/malayalam-font-in-nokia-n8) one which should be closed on sight), and very much language dependent (Malayalam is my native language).

Comment: Great Stack Overflow Tag 'Cleanup' of 2012 took the axe to a lot of language tags, as I recall, despite a somewhat-less-than-consensus that it was a good idea

Answer (score 8):

There's precedent for tags for languages with unusual alphabets. Compare [arabic](/questions/tagged/arabic), [hebrew](/questions/tagged/hebrew), and [hindi](/questions/tagged/hindi).

Comment: See also [tag:hindi].

Comment: Though, for some reason, not [tag:chinese].

Comment: Odd. No Japanese or Korean either.

Comment: All of those language fall under CJK - Chinese, Japanese, and Korean.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the tag wiki excerpt needs to mention the font that most of the 5 questions refer to.  It seems like all the questions tagged with it are specific about the language one way or another, so it seems appropriate to me.